# Cannot print entire doubly linked-list elements to console

Tags: swift, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have implemented a doubly linked list in Swift. Everything is going fine. The links are well set up and I can access every element using nextNode and previousNode properties. But when I print the list to the console, it just prints out the head of the list.

```
import Foundation

struct DoublyLinkedList<DataItem> {
    fileprivate var head : Node<DataItem>?
    fileprivate var tail : Node<DataItem>?

    var isEmpty : Bool {
        return head == nil
    }

    //to add at the beginning
    mutating func InsertAtBeginning(_ dataItem : DataItem) {
        let node = Node(dataItem: dataItem, nextNode: head, previousNode: nil)
        head?.previousNode = node
        head = node
        if tail == nil {
            tail = head
        }
    }

    //to add at the end
    mutating func insertAtEnd(_ dataItem : DataItem) {
        guard !isEmpty else {
            InsertAtBeginning(dataItem)
            return
        }

        let newNode = Node(dataItem: dataItem, nextNode: nil, previousNode: tail)
        tail?.nextNode = newNode
        //newNode.previousNode = tail
        tail = newNode

    }
}

extension DoublyLinkedList : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description : String {
        guard let doublyLinkedListHead = head else { return "UnderFlow"}
        return String(describing: doublyLinkedListHead)
    }
}

class Node<DataItem> {
    var dataItem : DataItem
    var nextNode : Node?
    var previousNode : Node?

    init(dataItem : DataItem , nextNode : Node? = nil , previousNode : Node? = nil) {
        self.dataItem = dataItem
        self.nextNode = nextNode
        self.previousNode = previousNode
    }
}

extension Node : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "\(dataItem) "
    }
}

var list = DoublyLinkedList<Int>()
list.InsertAtBeginning(4)
list.InsertAtBeginning(7)
print(list)
list.insertAtEnd(5)
list.insertAtEnd(4)
print(list)
let node1 = list.head?.nextNode
node1?.previousNode
list.tail?.previousNode?.previousNode
```

When I print a `node` it should print the `node` and one `nextNode` and one `previousNode` of the `node` and when I print the `list`, it should print the entire list. For example, when I access `head` it should return `nil <-> 7 <-> 4`. When I print `list`, it should give all the elements.

Comment: Hint: One node's description need to include the description of its `nextNode`, which needs to include a description of *its* `nextNode`.

Comment: I guess you need to walk the list and print items along the way. It shouldn't be that hard and actually is the fun of working with a (doubly) linked list.

Comment: I gave you two links to existing implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021105/how-to-implement-doubly-linked-list-in-swift#comment100572860_57021105). Both demonstrate how to print a linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation that meets your requirements.

`description` for a `Node` now returns `previousNode!.dataItem <-> dataItem <-> nextNode!dataItem`.  If `previousNode` or `nextNode` is `nil`, then `nil` will be printed.

`description` for a `DoublyLinkedList` will use the `linkedDescription` of a `Node` to provide a recursive description of the list.  Each `Node`'s `linkedDescription` will include the `Node`s `dataItem` plus the `linkedDescription` of the `nextNode` if it isn't `nil`.  `<->` is used between the nodes to represent the links.

```
extension DoublyLinkedList : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description : String {
        guard let doublyLinkedListHead = head else { return "UnderFlow"}
        return doublyLinkedListHead.linkedDescription
    }
}

extension Node : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return
        ((previousNode == nil) ? "nil" : "\(previousNode!.dataItem)") +
        " <-> \(dataItem) <-> " +
        ((nextNode == nil) ? "nil" : "\(nextNode!.dataItem)")
    }

    var linkedDescription: String {
        return "\(dataItem)" + ((nextNode == nil) ? "" : " <-> \(nextNode!.linkedDescription)")
    }
}
```

This will recursively provide the entire list when you `print(list)`.  When you `print(node)`, it will provide `previousNode!.dataItem <-> dataItem <-> nextNode!.dataItem`.

---

**Example:**

```
var list = DoublyLinkedList<Int>()
list.InsertAtBeginning(4)
list.InsertAtBeginning(7)
print(list)
```

> ```
> 7 <-> 4
> ```

```
print(list.head!)
```

> ```
> nil <-> 7 <-> 4
> ```

```
list.insertAtEnd(5)
list.insertAtEnd(4)
print(list)
```

> ```
> 7 <-> 4 <-> 5 <-> 4
> ```

```
print(list.head!.nextNode!)
```

> ```
> 7 <-> 4 <-> 5
> ```

Comment: i did this exactly but this only shows the nextNode values when we access a particular node. for example if i access head.nextNode, it will return 4 <-> 5 <-> 4. what i want to print is actually that it should return only one nextNode and one previousNode of the node that we access and when we print the list, it should print the entire list.         for example....when i access head it should return nil <-> 7 <->4. when i print list, it should give all the elements.      well i am trying to do it since day before yesterday! Is it possible? if no then why? thanks for ur help sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Here is the full implementation of doubly-linked-list. updates will be appreciated. 



import Foundation

struct DoublyLinkedList<DataItem> {

    fileprivate var head : Node<DataItem>?
    fileprivate var tail : Node<DataItem>?
    var isEmpty : Bool {
        return head == nil
    }

    //to add at the beginning
    mutating func InsertAtBeginning(_ dataItem : DataItem) {
        let node = Node(dataItem: dataItem, nextNode: head, previousNode: nil)
        head?.previousNode = node
        head = node
        if tail == nil {
            tail = head
        }
    }

    //to add at the end
    mutating func insertAtEnd(_ dataItem : DataItem) {
        guard !isEmpty else {
            InsertAtBeginning(dataItem)
            return
        }

        let newNode = Node(dataItem: dataItem, nextNode: nil, previousNode: tail)
        tail?.nextNode = newNode
        //newNode.previousNode = tail
        tail = newNode

    }

    //to insert at particular node
    func insertParticularly(_ dataItem : DataItem , afterNode : Node<DataItem>) {
        let node = Node(dataItem: dataItem)
        afterNode.nextNode?.previousNode = node
        node.nextNode = afterNode.nextNode
        afterNode.nextNode = node
        node.previousNode = afterNode


    }

    //to find a node at particular index
    func findNode(at index : Int) -> Node<DataItem>? {
        var currentIndex = 0
        var currentNode =  head
        while currentNode != nil && currentIndex < index {
            currentNode = currentNode?.nextNode
            currentIndex += 1
        }
        return currentNode
    }

    //MARK:- remove functionality

    //remove the first element
    mutating func removeFirst() -> DataItem? {

        defer {
            head = head?.nextNode
            if isEmpty {
                head = nil
            }
        }

        return head?.dataItem
    }

    // remove the last element
    mutating func removeLast() -> DataItem? {


        guard let headValue = head else {
            return nil
        }

        guard headValue.nextNode != nil else {
            return removeFirst()
        }

        var previous = headValue
        var current = headValue

        while let next = current.nextNode {
            previous = current
            current = next
        }

        previous.nextNode = nil
        tail = previous
        return current.dataItem

    }

    // remove from a specific location
    mutating func removeAt(at node : Node<DataItem>?) -> DataItem? {
        defer {
            if node === tail {
                removeLast()
            }
            node?.previousNode?.nextNode = node?.nextNode
            node?.nextNode?.previousNode = node?.previousNode
        }
        return node?.nextNode?.dataItem
    }

}

extension DoublyLinkedList : CustomStringConvertible {

    var description : String {
        guard let doublyLinkedListHead = head else { return "UnderFlow"}
        //return String(describing: doublyLinkedListHead)
        return doublyLinkedListHead.linkedDescription
    }

}

class Node<DataItem> {
    var dataItem : DataItem
    var nextNode : Node?
    var previousNode : Node?



    init(dataItem : DataItem , nextNode : Node? = nil , previousNode : Node? = nil) {
        self.dataItem = dataItem
        self.nextNode = nextNode
        self.previousNode = previousNode
    }
}

extension Node : CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        return ((previousNode == nil) ? "nil" : "\(previousNode!.dataItem)") +
                " <-> \(dataItem) <-> " +
            ((nextNode == nil) ? "nil" : "\(nextNode!.dataItem)")
    }
        var linkedDescription: String {
            return "\(dataItem)" + ((nextNode == nil) ? "" : " <-> \(nextNode!.linkedDescription)")

        }

}


var list = DoublyLinkedList<Int>()
list.InsertAtBeginning(4)
list.insertAtEnd(5)
list.insertAtEnd(4)
list.insertAtEnd(7)
list.insertAtEnd(2)
list.insertAtEnd(0)

list.description
let node1 = list.findNode(at: 3)
node1?.previousNode
list.head
```